# Merging data from a data frame with data from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, merge

I have a dictionary with keys that are a date time, and values that are data frames from that day, like so:

```
dict = {dt.datetime(2021,11,1):pd.DataFrame({'team':['horses','eagles'],
                                             'rating':[15,20]}),
        dt.datetime(2021,11,2):pd.DataFrame({'team':['horses','eagles'],
                                             'rating':[35,50]})}

{datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 0, 0):
      team  rating
0  horses      15
1  eagles      20,
 datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 2, 0, 0):
      team  rating
0  horses      35
1  eagles      50}
```

I also have a separate data frame with a date time column and the names of those teams in the same row, like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime(2021,11,1),dt.datetime(2021,11,2)],
                       'team_1':'horses',
                       'team_2':'eagles'})

        date  team_1  team_2
0 2021-11-01  horses  eagles
1 2021-11-02  horses  eagles
```

What I would like to do is to iterate through the dictionary so that if the datetime key matches a date in the date column of df, then to take the data from the value and merge it to teams in df to create a final data frame, like so:

```
        date  team_1  team_1_rating  team_2  team_2_rating
0 2021-11-01  horses             15  eagles             20
1 2021-11-02  horses             35  eagles             50
```

I tried to iterate through the dictionary and merge the data with this code:

```
for key, value in dict.items:
    if key == df['date']:
        final_df = pd.merge(df,value,left_on = ['team_1','team_2'], right_on = 'team')
```

But I get an error like

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm not quite sure if this is a good way to do it or not but any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Don't use `dict`, it is a reserved keyword in Python. Instead use `my_dict` or similar

Comment: Would recommend using `pandas.Timestamp` instead of `datetime.datetime`

Comment: Also while it's clear you have tried to provide all your code, there are a few things missing/that would make it easier for people trying to help you. Don't split your code into blocks because it makes it hard to put together to attempt to replicate the error. Also include whatever imports you have. See [mre] for some more info

Answer (score 0):

The error lies here:

```
if key == df['date']:
```

It says it is ambiguous, because indeed, it doesn't know to which cell to compare it.

For example:

```
x = '2021-11-01'
if x == df['date']:
    print ("hola")
```

It will give you that error.

So,you will need to loop through df.iloc

Comment: I'm checking my assumptions; I think it is possible to use Python's `if [a] in [b]` construction here; yes, the error is where you say it is, but I don't think looping through `df.iloc` is the best nor the most pythonic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the line `if key == df['date']` doesn't do what you think it does. You are comparing if key (which is a datetime object) is the same as `df['date']`, which is a `pandas.Series`. Because these two objects are not a `str`, `int`, `float` etc, Python tries to compare the `bool` of each of the two. This exception is raised when you try to get the `bool` of a `pandas.Series`.

You could use a for loop to iterate through each value in `df['data']`, but a much cleaner method is to use the built-in Pandas functionality of `loc` (docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc)).

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_dict = {dt.datetime(2021,11,1):pd.DataFrame({'team':['horses','eagles'],
                                             'rating':[15,20]}),
        dt.datetime(2021,11,2):pd.DataFrame({'team':['horses','eagles'],
                                             'rating':[35,50]})}

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime(2021,11,1),dt.datetime(2021,11,2)],
                       'team_1':'horses',
                       'team_2':'eagles'})

# Searching for key match in df
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    df.loc[df['date'] == key, 'team_1_rating'] = value['rating'][0]
    df.loc[df['date'] == key, 'team_2_rating'] = value['rating'][1]

# Reordering columns to match desired output
col_list = list(df)
col_list[2], col_list[3] = col_list[3], col_list[2]
df.columns = col_list

print(df)
```

Note the bottom block just reorders your dataframe to match your desired output.